# The rice and chess problem

Tags: code-golf, math

An Indian legend tells the story of the alleged inventor of the chess game, who impressed the emperor of India with his game so much that he would get rewarded with anything asked.

The man said he wanted to be paid in rice. He wanted a grain of rice for the first square of the chessboard, two for the second, four for the third, eight for the fourth, and so on, until the 64th square.

The emperor was amazed that the man asked for such a small reward, but as his mathematicians started counting, he ended up losing one of his provinces.

## Task

Given the length of the side of a hypothetical chessboard (which is 8 on a default chessboard) and the multiplier between squares (which is 2 in the legend), calculate the number of grains of rice the emperor must pay to the man.

## Notes

- The side length will always be a positive integer. The multiplier could instead be any kind of rational number.
- If your language of choice can't display very large numbers, it's okay as long as your program can correctly process smaller inputs.
- Also if your language of choice rounds larger values (with exponential notations), it's okay if those values are approximately correct.

## Testcases

```
Input (side length, multiplier) => Output
8, 2                            => 18446744073709551615
3, 6                            => 2015539
7, 1.5                          => 850161998.2854
5, -3                           => 211822152361
256, 1                          => 65536
2, 2                            => 15
2, -2                           => -5
```

Please note that the explicit formula

```
result = (multiplier ^ (side ^ 2) - 1) / (multiplier - 1)
```

Performs wrong on `multiplier = 1`, as

```
1 ^ (side ^ 2) - 1 = 0
1 - 1 = 0
0 / 0 != side ^ 2 (as it should be)
```

## Scoring

This is code-golf. Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: You probably want a test case where the multiplier is 1 and another where it is 0 (assuming both are valid). Also "anything" is pretty broad, does the square root of negative one count? How about "potato"? ;) I'd recommend "any real number" or something.

Comment: `If your language of choose can't display too large numbers, it's ok as long as your program can correctly process smaller inputs` Careful, that has caused problems in the past. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8245/31716

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203824/what-is-xy-how-to-understand-it/204461#204461

Comment: ... it must have been a rich province, because even today, the yearly world production of rice is still less than 2^64 grains.

Comment: So you ask us to implement an explicit formula? `f(s,m)=(m^(s^2)-1)/(m-1)`? I bet that is a dupe.

Comment: I thought the formula would make this trivial, but it not working for `m=1` means that both summing a list and a recursive/iterative expression seem to be competitive options in non-golfing languages.

Comment: @vsz Actually, the guy was killed. The amount added to the king giving away the entire kingdom to the man, so naturally the easier way out was taken.

Comment: @cst1992 the version I read says the man gave up on his request and got a province as a gift.

Comment: `result = ... / (multiplier - 1)`, not +

Comment: This is `s^m^2-1`, right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
²b1ḅ
```

This uses the approach from [@APLDude's clever APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79335).

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrJiMeG4hQ&input=&args=OA+Mg) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrJiMeG4hQrDpyJH&input=&args=OCwgMywgICA3LCAgNSwgMjU2LCAyLCAgMg+MiwgNiwgMS41LCAtMywgICAxLCAyLCAtMg).

#### How it works

```
²b1ḅ  Main link. Arguments: x (side length), y (multiplier)

²     Square; yield x².
 b1   Convert to base 1 (unary), yielding a list of x² ones.
   ḅ  Convert from base y to real number.
      This yields y^(x²-1) + ... + y + 1.
```

Answer (score 28):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
2^:q^s
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Ml46cV5z&input=NwoxLjU)

```
2^   % Take implicit input, say N, and square it: N^2
:q   % Generate array [0 1 ... N^2-1]
^    % Take implicit input, M, and compute [M^0 M^1 ... M^(N^2-1)]
s    % Sum of the array. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 23):

## APL, 10 bytes

```
⎕⊥1+0×⍳⎕*2
```

`⎕` is used to read user input twice. If we store the side length in **s** and the multiplier in **m**, we get the following code.

```
m⊥1+0×⍳s*2
```

And here's how APL parses this code:

[image: Explanation of algorithm]

Comment: Or as a function train: [`⊣⊥1⍴⍨⊢×⊢`](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u22A2%u22A51%u2374%u2368%u22A3%D7%u22A3%20%u22C4%208%20f%202%20%u22C4%203%20f%206%20%u22C4%207%20f%201.5%20%u22C4%205%20f%20%AF3%20%u22C4%20256%20f%201%20%u22C4%202%20f%202%20%u22C4%202%20f%20%AF2&run) (8 bytes) As an interactive REPL command, `⎕⊥×⍳⎕*2` (7 bytes) works as well.

Answer (score 19):

### Python, 40 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:eval('1+m*('*n*n+'0'+')'*n*n)
```

Generates and evaluates a string like

```python
1+m*(1+m*(1+m*(1+m*(0))))
```

that encodes the sum as a [Hornerized polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) with `n*n` terms.

A lot of different methods gave very similar byte counts:

```python
#String evaluation
lambda n,m:eval('1+m*('*n*n+'0'+')'*n*n)   #40

#Direct summation
lambda n,m:sum(m**i for i in range(n*n))   #40
lambda n,m:sum(map(m.__pow__,range(n*n)))  #41

#Direct formula
lambda n,m:n*n*(1==m)or(m**n**2-1)/(m-1)   #40

#Iterative sequence
f=lambda n,m,j=0:j<n*n and 1+m*f(n,m,j+1)  #41
def f(n,m):s=0;exec"s=s*m+1;"*n*n;print s  #41

#Recursive expression
#Fails due to float imprecision of square root
f=lambda n,m:n and 1+m*f((n*n-1)**.5,m)    #39*
```

Comment: Ah right, my bad. Anyway, I really like seeing all the different approaches you took :)

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to [@FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman).

```
s^Lvz*
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5ELvz*&input=8%0A2&debug=0)

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5ELvz*&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=8%0A2%0A3%0A6%0A7%0A1.5%0A5%0A-3&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES2016/ES7), <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
a=>b=>(b**(a*a)-1)/--b||a*a
```

Just @Bassdrop Cumberwubwubwub and @Kaizo's ES6 version, but with exponentiation operator. :) (I didn't have enough reputation to comment instead.)

Edit: `/+(b-1)` changed to `/--b` (thanks @Neil).

Edit: now uses currying (thanks @MamaFunRoll).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Your answer is pretty good!

Comment: Welcome! The `+` operator was a test I forgot to edit out, so you can shave off 1 byte by omitting it :)

Comment: The formula doesn't work for m = 1 :3

Comment: @user6245072 are you on chrome canary? Or on node? If on node, enable harmony flag

Comment: Would `/--b` save you a byte or two?

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub and Neil thanks, I've made the changes. (Not had a chance to test though.)

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub seriously though, you should get the credit for this answer :) (well, and @Neil)

Comment: Currying can save you a byte. `a=>b=>`

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, 25 bytes

```haskell
n%m=sum$(m^)<$>[0..n*n-1]
```

Sums the list `[m^0, m^1, ..., m^(n*n-1)]`.

Answer (score 10):

## Jelly, 6 bytes

```
²R’*@S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrJS4oCZKkBT&input=&args=OA+Mg)

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript ES6, <s>59</s> <s>37</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
a=>b=>(Math.pow(b,a*a)-1)/--b||a*a`
```

Thanks to @Kaizo for shaving off a whopping 19 bytes, @Neil for another 2 and @gcampbell for 1 more!

Try it here

```js
f=
a=>b=>(Math.pow(b,a*a)-1)/--b||a*a

a.innerHTML='<pre>'+
  [[8,2],
   [3,6],
   [7,1.5],
   [5,-3],
   [256,1],
   [2,2],
   [2,-2]].map(b=>`${b[0]}, ${b[1]} => ${f(b[0])(b[1])}`).join('<br>')+'</pre>'
```

```html
<div id=a>
```

## Alternative broken versions

**32 bytes**

```
(a,b)=>(Math.pow(b,a*a)-1)/(b-1)
```

Causes `NaN` for `b==1`.

**30 bytes**

```
(a,b)=>(Math.pow(b,a*a)-1)/~-b
```

Causes `Infinity` for `b==1.5`.

**28 bytes**

```
(a,b)=>~-Math.pow(b,a*a)/~-b
```

Outputs `1` for some valid testcases.

## Old version for 59 bytes

``` (a,b)=>Array(a*a).fill``.reduce((c,d,i)=>c+Math.pow(b,i),0) ```

Comment: Why haven't you just treated the b==1 case in the 32 bytes case? 40 bytes: (a,b)=>b-1?(Math.pow(b, a * a)-1)/(b-1):a*a

Comment: @Kaizo you're right, I'm an idiot :D

Comment: `/~-b` is obviously no good for fractional `b`, but `/--b` should work, no?

Comment: By the way, I golfed the old version down to 47 bytes: `(a,b)=>[...Array(a*a-1)].reduce(s=>s+=p*=b,p=1)`

Comment: @Neil you're right, ofcourse. That's what you get when you rush your answers :p Thanks!

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub you can curry it to save a byte (thanks @MamaFunRoll).

Answer (score 8):

## MATLAB, 23 bytes

```
@(n,k)sum(k.^(0:n^2-1))
```

Test it [here](https://ideone.com/pu3jdZ)!

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 132 bytes

```
import java.math.*;Object e(int n,BigDecimal m){BigDecimal r=BigDecimal.ONE,a=r;for(n*=n;n>1;n--)r=r.add(a=a.multiply(m));return r;}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
import java.math.*;

Object e(int n, BigDecimal m) {
    BigDecimal r = BigDecimal.ONE, a = r;
    for (n *= n; n > 1; n--)
        r = r.add(a = a.multiply(m));
    return r;
}
```

#### Notes

- This will work for arbitrarily big outputs as required by OP (Too bad Java supports big numbers, this would be shorter otherwise).

#### Outputs

```
Input:      8 2.0
Expected:   18446744073709551615
Actual:     18446744073709551615

Input:      3 6.0
Expected:   2015539
Actual:     2015539

Input:      7 1.5
Expected:   850161998.2854
Actual:     850161998.285399449204543742553141782991588115692138671875

Input:      5 -3.0
Expected:   211822152361
Actual:     211822152361

Input:      256 1.0
Expected:   65536
Actual:     65536

Input:      2 2.0
Expected:   15
Actual:     15

Input:      2 -2.0
Expected:   -5
Actual:     -5

Input:      263 359.9
Expected:   ?
Actual:     9709...[176798 digits]...7344.7184...[69160 digits]...6291
```

Answer (score 6):

## R, 18 bytes

```
sum(m^(1:s^2-1))
```

Explanation:

```
sum(               # Calculate sum
    m              # Multiplier
     ^             # Exponentiate
      (1:s^2-1))   # Generate sequence from 1 to s(ide)^2-1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
nL<mO
```

Explanation:

```
n      # Compute i ** 2
 L     # Push the list [1, ..., i ** 2]
  <    # Decrement by 1, [0, ..., i ** 2 - 1]
   m   # Power function with implicit input, [0 ** j, ..., (i ** 2 - 1) ** j]
    O  # Sum that all up
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=bkw8bU8&input=OAoy).

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 30 bytes

```
n#m=sum$take(n^2)$iterate(*m)1
```

or equally long

```
n%1=n^2
n%m=(m**(n*n)-1)/(m-1)
```

The first version starts with `1` repeatedly multiplies with `m`. Then it sums the first `n^2` numbers of this sequence. The second version is the explicit formula as seen in other answers.

Comment: Can't you just do `n#m=sum$(m^)<$>[0..n*n-1]`?

Comment: @xnor: oh, that's nice. I think it's different enough for a separate answer. Please post it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 10 bytes

```
+/@:^i.@*:
```

### Usage

I mark some integers with the `x` suffix to use extended integers to get exact results.

```
   f =: +/@:^i.@*:
   2x f 8
18446744073709551615
   3x f 6
75047317648499560
   6x f 3
2015539
   1.5 f 7
8.50162e8
   _3x f 5
211822152361
   1 f 256
65536
   2 f 2
15
   _2 f 2
_5
```

### Explanation

```
+/@:^i.@*:
        *:  Square the value s to get s^2
     i.@    Make a range from 0 to s^2 exclusive, [0, 1, ..., s^2-1]
    ^       Using m as the base, calculate the power with the range
            [m^0, m^1, ..., m^(s^2-1)]
+/@:        Sum the entire list and return it
```

Comment: 6 bytes `#.*:$*` as per APL Dude.

Answer (score 4):

## PostgreSQL, <strike>67</strike> 66 bytes

```
SELECT SUM(m^v)FROM(VALUES(3,6))t(s,m),generate_series(0,s*s-1)s(v)
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8180/0)**</kbd>

Input: `VALUES(side, multiplier)`

---

**EDIT:**

Input moved to table, all cases at-once:

```
SELECT s,m,SUM(m^v)FROM i,generate_series(0,s*s-1)s(v)GROUP BY s,m
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/17f35/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════════════════════╗
║  s   ║  m   ║         sum          ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════════════════════╣
║   7  ║ 1.5  ║ 850161998.2853994    ║
║   2  ║ 2    ║ 15                   ║
║   2  ║ -2   ║ -5                   ║
║ 256  ║ 1    ║ 65536                ║
║   5  ║ -3   ║ 211822152361         ║
║   8  ║ 2    ║ 18446744073709552000 ║
║   3  ║ 6    ║ 2015539              ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 4):

### Mathcad, [tbd] bytes (~11)

[image]

Uses Mathcad's built in summation operator.  Also demonstrates symbolic processor simplification to generate exact formula.

Mathcad effectively runs two processing engines in parallel - one a standard IEEE 64/80 bit floating point, and the other an arbitrary number length symbolic process (MuPad).  Standard numerical evaluation is indicated by equals sign (=), whilst a right arrow indicates symbolic evaluation.

---

Mathcad counting scheme yet to be determined so no byte count given.

ctl-$ enters the summation operator (Sigma), including empty placeholders to put the summation variable, initial value, final value and expression. Approximate byte-equivalent count = 11.

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: The "code" for the actual challenge is the first summation sign (capital Sigma) you see under the heading "Challeng Solution".  The other bits of "code" are given under the heading "Solution Variants".   What you see in the image is exactly what gets written down on a Mathcad worksheet - Mathcad uses mathematical symbols for various operations, such as a vector sum or product, function integration or differentiation, or logical operations.  Most operators can be input with a key combination (for example, ctl-4 for an implicit vector sum or ctl-& for an iterated sum), or via a menu or toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 40 bytes

```
lambda l,m:sum(m**i for i in range(l*l))
```

Comment: `lambda l,m:(m**(l*l)-1)/(m-1)`

Comment: In regular languages using formula would be shorter. I used map because in esolangs maps would be shorter.

Comment: Where's the strikethrough?

Comment: @KennyLau I was still working on my answer, I posted this before seeing your comment.

Comment: Alright, (7 more to go...)

Comment: Wouldn't work if `m==1`...

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 19 bytes

`S` is side length, and `M` is the multiplier.

```
Prompt S,M:Σ(M^I,I,0,S²-1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby: 39 bytes

```
->s,m{(0...s*s).reduce(0){|a,b|a+m**b}}
```

**Test:**

```
f = ->s,m{(0...s*s).reduce(0){|a,b|a+m**b}}

f[8,2]   # 18446744073709551615
f[3,6]   # 2015539
f[7,1.5] # 850161998.2853994
f[5,-3]  # 211822152361
f[256,1] # 65536
f[2,2]   # 15
f[2,-2]  # -5
f[1,1]   # 1
```

Comment: When did Ruby get a `sum` function??? This is gamechanging

Comment: Oh no! What I thought was a ruby core method is in fact a [rails method](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) *sad face*.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can you just change your language to Rails? I don't know about any imports you might need for that

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 41 Bytes

Totally new at this golfing thing, criticism welcome!

```
lambda n,m:sum(m**i for i in range(n**2))
```

Comment: It's actually quite good ; )

Comment: Haha, thanks. I had to google how to do lambdas in python again, since I haven't touched python in a while.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This is a nice answer, but it's rather similar to [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79248).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see if there were any other solutions. Did he save a byte by doing `l**l` instead of what I did?

Comment: `l*l` actually, which is shorter than `l**2`.

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks to Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ for saving 3 bytes and pointing me towards mapping*

```
uΜzQjd^JwH
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=dc6celFqZF5Kd0g)

```
 ΜzQj       Map over an array of 1 -> square(side length)
     d^JwH  Set the current array value to multiplier^(current value - 1)
u           Sum the array
```

Comment: Nice work! You can remove the a before the zeta, as that is implicitly outed. You can also use Mu (map) instead of for each, and I think you can replace the D with a d and remove the ending }.

Comment: @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ Neat, keep forgetting about the implicit parts of Jolf, they are certainly some of the best ways to shave off a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 22 bytes

```
Tr[#^(Range[#2^2]-1)]&
```

Creates a range of `{1, 2, ... s^2}`, subtracts 1 over it to make `{0, 1, ..., s^2-1}`. Then raise each to the power of `m` making `{m^0, m^1, ..., m^(s^2-1)}` and return the sum of it.

Alternatively, Mathematica can use the explicit formula by taking its limit. This requires **29** bytes.

```
Limit[(s^#^2-1)/(s-1),s->#2]&
```

Comment: You could write your first version as `Tr[#^Range[#2^2]/#]&`

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 9 bytes

```
q~2#,f#:+
```

Inputs are in reverse order separated by a newline or a space.

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX4yIyxmIzor&input=MS41Cjc)

```
q~    e# Read input. Evaluate: pushes the two numbers, M and N, onto the stack
2#    e# Square: compute N^2
,     e# Range: generates array [0 1 ... N^2-1]
f#    e# Compute M raised to each element of the array [0 1 ... N^2-1]
:+    e# Fold addition: compute sum of the array [M^0 M^1 ... M^(N^2-1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```
<?function a($n,$m){$n*=$n;echo(1-$m**$n)/(1-$m)?:$n;}
```

This just uses the summation formula to show the value, after checking if the multiplier is 1 (which returns NAN in the formula).

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 25 bytes

```
f(s,m)=sum(i=0,s^2-1,m^s)
```

Longer but faster (35 bytes):

```
f(s,m)=if(m==1,s^2,(m^s^2-1)/(m-1))
```

Cute (30 bytes):

```
f(s,m)=vecsum(powers(m,s^2-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <strike>54</strike> 47 bytes

```
r=0l,m=...for i=0,l^2-1 do r=r+m^i end print(r)
```

Run from the command line with the board side length as the first argument and the multiplier as the second.

Thanks to user6245072 for saving 6 bytes, and Katenkyo for saving an additional 1.

---

Original 54 byte version:

```
a,b=...c=1 d=1 for i=2,a^2 do c=c*b d=d+c end print(d)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Great answer!

Comment: `l,m=...r=0 for i=0,l^2 do r=r+m^i end print(r)`

Comment: This should save some bytes.

Comment: renaming d saves one byte because it allows to skip the space in `c=1 d=1` => `a,b=...c=1g=1 for i=2,a^2 do c=c*b g=g+c end print(g)`. if @user6245072 's suggestion works, you could save a byte on the same principle => `r=0l,m=...for i=0,l^2 do r=r+m^i end print(r)`

Comment: The whitespace between `r=0` and `l,m=...` is anyway compulsory, so it doesn't change. Also the loop should be  `for i=0,l^2-1` but this is my fault lol.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 56 bytes

```
double f(int n,double q){return(Math.Pow(q,n*n)-1)/--q;}
```

Comment: Testcase `256, 1`?

Comment: Is it not 256^2?

Comment: `(Math.Pow(1, 256 * 256) - 1) / --1` = 0/0.

Comment: You need either using System; or System.Math.Pow. And your code doesn't work, when q=1, as stated by @user6245072.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 17 bytes

A non-tacit solution, by defining a dyad:

```
f=:4 :'+/y^i.x^2'
```

e.g.

```
8x f 2

18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 11 chars / 14 bytes

```
⨭⩥ î²)ⓜⁿ⁽í$
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox/WebKit Nightly only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B8%2C2%5D&code=%E2%A8%AD%E2%A9%A5%20%C3%AE%C2%B2%29%E2%93%9C%E2%81%BF%E2%81%BD%C3%AD%24)</kbd>

Yes,  now works in WebKit Nightly! Chrome support is next.

## Explanation

```
⨭⩥ î²)ⓜⁿ⁽í$ // implicit: î = input1, í = input2
   ⩥ î²)       // generate a range [0..î^2)
                     ⓜ      // map over range ($ is mapitem):
        ⁿ⁽í$  //   í^$
⨭            // sum resulting range
              // implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 32 bytes

```
[a:2^0\
{[$¥][a;\^]#[¤¥][+]#]!
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda that leaves result on Stack2. Usage:

```
8 2[a:2^0\
{[$¥][a;\^]#[¤¥][+]#]!
```

## Explanation

```
[                              ]!  lambda
 a:                                store multiplier to a
   2^                              square side-length
     0\␊                           create range [0..result)
        {                          set current stack to range
         [  ][     ]#              while loop
          $¥                         check if TOS is truthy
              a;\^␌                  if so, push a^TOS to Stack2
                     ␁            set current stack to Stack2
                       [¤¥][+]#    sum Stack2
```

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 9 bytes

```
╗²r`╜ⁿ`MΣ
```

Takes input as side length first, then multiplier.

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWXwrJyYOKVnOKBv2BNzqM&input=OAoy)

Explanation:

```
╗²r`╜ⁿ`MΣ
╗          save m to reg0
 ²r        range(s**2) ([0, s**2-1])
   `  `M   map (for n in list):
    ╜ⁿ       m**n (m is pushed from reg0)
        Σ  sum
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
XUm^s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=XUm%5Es&input=2%0A-2)

```
X     - input()**2
 U   - range(0,^)
  m^  - map(^,^)
    s - sum(^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 4 bytes

```
²r#Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxdCsIwEITfc4qlPrdkN5lN8iB4E5HiT0EtpH0TT@MNvIDQA3ilGBGEgWG@Yeaym0/H8XwoZXnm1ftRtpv18ro1NEzUjznv@7m5/@Jw/YMSSYij9xq8t8EFmwBWhnGkJJYBl0wg7kARtjYpxU4ivAG1joQ5ijDEKRuBEpPWiRr5/qJaW4UP)

### Explanation

Basically a port of Luis Mendo's MATL answer, but uses some implicit operating magic of MathGolf.

```
²      Square the first input
 r     Create range [0, 1, ..., N^2-1]
  #    Map (2nd input)^i for i in the array
   Σ   Sum the array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
²L*
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCMkwqJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9NyUwQTEuNSZmbGFncz1TZQ==)

Port of Luis Mendo's MATL answer.

##### Explanation

```python
²L*  # Implicit input
²    # Square the first input
 L   # Push [0..that)
  *  # Take the second input
     # to the power of each
     # Sum the resulting list
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 48 bytes

```
x=>y=>x==1?y*y:(System.Math.Pow(x,y*y)-1)/(x-1);
```

Where x is the multiplier, y is the side length. It uses the explicit formula for the sum of the geometric series, which is a1*(q^n-1)/(q-1), if q!=1, n*a1, if q==1.

Answer (score 0):

## k, <s>16</s> 11 bytes

Bytes shaved using the technique from a [clever answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79335/42775).

```
{y/(x*x)#1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qulJfo0KrQlPZsPZ/mp66hoWCkbWxgpm1uYKhnqm1qYKusbWRqZmCobURUMJIQddI8z8A) <sub>(There seems to be some sort of rounding happening for large numbers.)</sub>

Explanation:

```
{         } /function, x is board length, y is multiplier
   (x*x)#1  /make a list with as many 1s as there are board squares
 y/         /read as base y number
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 48 bytes

```
param($l,$m,$r)$c=1;1..$l*$l|%{$r+=$c;$c*=$m};$r
```

Test script:

```
$f = {
    param($l,$m,$r)$c=1;1..$l*$l|%{$r+=$c;$c*=$m};$r
}

@(
    ,(8, 2    ,18446744073709551615)
    ,(3, 6    ,2015539)
    ,(7, 1.5  ,850161998.2854)
    ,(5, -3   ,211822152361)
    ,(256, 1  ,65536)
    ,(2, 2    ,15)
    ,(2, -2   ,-5)
) | %{
    $x,$n,$e = $_
    $r = &$f $x $n
    "$($e-eq$r): $r $e"
}
```

Output:

```
False: 1.84467440737096E+19 18446744073709551615
True: 2015539 2015539
False: 850161998.285399 850161998.2854
True: 211822152361 211822152361
True: 65536 65536
True: 15 15
True: -5 -5
```

Differences from rounding are permitted by rules.

`$r` is a local parameter. If a parameter omitted in a caller then `$r` will have the value `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-x`, 5 bytes

```
²o!pV
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=sm8hcFY=&input=Myw2Ci14)

Comment: Could you add an explanation of your solution for those not familiar with Japt?

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 51 bytes

```
let c s m=Seq.init(s*s)(fun x->m**float x)|>Seq.sum
```

Fairly straight-forward. Works as well when `m` is 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRa8IwEMff@ykOQWhKWpxSJ077Mva2wWCPzodQEhdo0ppchwO/e5d0tbrWe0nyu//dP7kIG@el4U1TcIQcLKjtBz8mUksMbWRJKGoNpzhTUSSKkiGcyDnzClurZrd50Wh@3kupMdsHvoViUgMzh2/YBuDCM@QWn5nltmM@dv3OR7iiME9m5Ok/XVBYjukjhYckHdKUQrwYi@fp0svH/K6ho/EdvBq22Aft1s9BsQraIYUF1wf8ohCqukBZFZKbdTszQiDO4JK@Zp007/BtEXH6fmStzzlrrSRyM/C6bWa4dSfv1d@zMu5nhIbJ6xqmksKbW8QnTsXk4ntt0NX3teTvjbPmFw)