# Calculate power series result

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, integer

<sup>*Related: [Calculate Power Series Coefficients](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105282/calculate-power-series-coefficients)*</sup>

Given a positive integer \$X\$ and a max exponent (Also a positive integer too) \$N\$ calculate the result of a power series. Example:

$$X^0+X^1+X^2+\cdots +X^N$$

- Assume \$(X + N)  \le 100\$

---

**Test Cases**

```
1 2  => 3
2 3  => 15
3 4  => 121
2 19 => 1048575
```

---

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Comment: It would open up some more possibilities if we could assume that \$ x\neq 1\$, then we could use \$ 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\$, but it is probably too late for that =)

Comment: I definitely remember this challenge appearing previously but I don't have time to look for a dupe now.

Comment: "Assume 0 ≤ (X + N) ..." - but X & N are positive integers, so should that read "Assume 0 < (X + N) ..." or should X & N be non-negative integers?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Most non-mathematicians would probably class zero as a positive integer

Comment: @BetaDecay really? Most non-mathematicians would probably class it as a "number" :p

Comment: [This is the potential dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79241/20260) I was thinking of, with a difference being that it goes to `n*n-1` rather than `n`. Since my vote hammers, I'll wait for others to say if this is dupe-worthy.

Comment: @BetaDecay Most of the world considers `0` to be neither positive nor negative. A couple of places (like France) don't consider positive to mean *strictly* positive, and treat `0` as both positive and negative.

Comment: This is a simply stated challenge with a clear title. Perhaps the other challenge with the irrelevant backstory and the confusing title should get the dupe label retroactively!

Comment: @ngm, I don't find the title of this question clear, whereas the other title references a classic question that I've seen in printed puzzle books. However, if you want to propose flipping the duplicate closure relationship the place to do it is a [meta-tag:specific-question] [meta-tag:discussion] question on meta.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
function(x,n)sum(x^(0:n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCJ0@zuDRXoyJOw8AqT1Pzf5qGoY6RJleahpGOMYgy1jGB8AwtNf8DAA)

Comment: I love the way vectors work in R

Comment: @BetaDecay maybe we should nominate R for the language of the month!

Comment: @giuseppe I've been thinking about that for a while now... let's target September? I'll post an answer in Meta.

Comment: @JayCe yeah, sounds good. We should open up the R chatroom again (for the third time; I've twice opened one and both times it has died due to inactivity); I'm sure I'd love to add to whatever description you end up going with on the submission :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

The straightforward approach:

```hs
x#n=sum$map(x^)[0..n]
```

For the case \$ x \neq 1 \$ we alternatively could use following function with the same length:

```hs
x#n=div(x*x^n-1)$x-1
```

This uses the fact that

\$ 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1} -1}{x-1} \forall x \neq 1.\$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0I5z7a4NFclN7FAoyJOM9pATy8v9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCioKxsul/AA)

Comment: also 21 bytes: `x#0=1;x#n=x^n+x#(n-1)`.

Comment: @nimi Oh that is clever:)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

```javascript
x=>g=n=>~n&&x*g(n-1)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcu7DkAwFADQ3Vd0kpYUt9VgqH8Rj4bIrSBi8uslYcF8coZqq5Z67qeVo21a12m369Jo1OWBvr8HhiIHFoKrLS52bKPRGtpRYJQIxkgcE@m9SVwkbwL1MXlZ@piAf4TiwSTNVabcCQ)

---

## Non-recursive (ES7), 23 bytes

Using the direct formula mentioned by @flawr:

```javascript
x=>n=>~-(x**++n)/~-x||n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvPDkAgHADgu6foWCypNBzqXcy/MftlmHUwrx4bF5y/fUO5lUs199NKwdaNb7V32oA2B8UuDKMICDuo23fwlYXFjk082g63mBOMBCGIMSSDN4mL5E1cfUxelj4m@D/y4sEkzVWm/Ak)

Comment: `x=>g=n=>n?g(n-1)*x+1:1`

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ÝmO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Nxc////TbiMAQ)

Explanation:

```
Input: 4, 3
Ý    [0..input] - [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
m    Vectorized exponent - [1, 3, 9, 27, 81]
O    Sum - 121
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
*Ż}S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r6O7a4P///xv9N7QEAA)

Comment: Not sure it's worth another answer to post this other 4 byter: `*ⱮS‘`

Comment: @JonathanAllan I actually edited that away (note: I do this pretty often), but, eh, a grace period exists. :P (It was actually me forgetting about vectorization of `*`...)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 40 bytes

```python
lambda x,n:sum(x**k for k in range(n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ8@quDRXo0JLK1shLb9IIVshM0@hKDEvPVUjT9tQU/N/QVFmXolGmoahjpGmJheMZ6RjjMQz1jFBkTO0BGoEAA)

`lambda x,n:sum(map(x.__pow__,range(n+1)))` is cool too but it's 1 byte longer lol.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>53</s> 46 bytes

```powershell
param($x,$n)0..$n|%{$o+=[math]::pow($x,$_)};$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VCRyVP00BPTyWvRrVaJV/bNjo3sSQj1sqqIL8cLBuvWWutkv///3@j/4aWAA)

Not bad for needing a .NET call for `pow`.

*-7 bytes thanks to mazzy.*

Comment: It's stupid, but this `param($x,$n)$s=0;0..$n|%{$s+=[math]::pow($x,$_)};$s` is shorter. I don't sure about `$s=0;`: this expression [is needed on a second run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)). Perhaps, it better to append `;rv s` to the end.

Comment: 2 bytes less: `param($x,$n,$s)0..$n|%{$s+=[math]::pow($x,$_)};$s`. A caller still sends 2 parameters.

Comment: @mazzy Thanks! There's no need to re-initialize `$s` if it's run as a full program (e.g., how it's done on Try It Online), so that saves a few more bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
:^sQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yquOPD/f0NLLiMA)

Takes input as `N` then `X`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), 17 bytes

```
I~xI(ax!i^+~ai)aP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/37OuwlMjsUIxM067LjFTMzHg/38jLkNLAA)

### Explanation

```
I~x               - Store the input in the variable x
   I(         )   - Loop until the top of the stack equals the input n
     a            - Push a
      x           - Push x
       !i         - Increment i
         ^        - Calculate the value of x^i
          +~a     - Add x^i to a and store in a
             i    - Push i
               aP - Print the value of a
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/),  <s>35</s>  32 bytes

-1 Thanks to tsh (`f(x,n-1)+x**n` -> `f(x,n-1)*x+1`)

<sup>Port of [Arnauld's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169566/53748) - not sure if it is the first, so do shout if you know who deserves the credit!</sup>

```python
f=lambda x,n:~n and f(x,n-1)+x**n
```

A recursive function which sums the terms right-to-left, with a base case of zero when `n` reaches `-1` (since `~(-1)` is `-1 - (-1)` which is `0` which is falsey).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwEETvfsXcuqurkNaLhXxMpAYL7bbUFCIl/npM0bkMw4M38zs8J21y9nZw471ziKLtR@G0gzl5KvNs@Bizn5bCoOgVREZQs4BqQbN3I7j@t7kxtweUzEuvgSpPW0yCTRPDYlser3UIqboU4@gCRbtrrQp@xO6nUGbOXw)**

---

My previous **35 byter**:

```python
lambda x,n:x^1and~-x**-~n/~-x or-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUzdCoIwGL3vKc6d@@SzULtJ2JtEsLCRoJ@yFixEX31t1Lk5v5zl45@ztNHqaxzNdO8NAksXbrWRfq9CWVa7nJLA7JKKdnZpAMEgUKpmNMRQDaPN3DLOf19fiLoDEhY3iFeFVWvYGKtsBI3VPV7v0W/FMT1Oxqug860Wxq/RVuWAiOIX)

#### How?

The `^` operator is bitwise-xor, so `x^1` is zero when `x` is one and non-zero otherwise.
In Python non-zeros are truthy, so the right of the logical `and` is executed when `x` is not one, but not executed when `x` is one, whereupon the right of the logical `or` is executed instead.

So, when `x` is one we execute
`-~n` which is equivalent to
`-1 * ~n` which is equivalent to
`-1 * (-1 - n)` which is equivalent to
`1 + n`...

...and when `x` is not one we execute
`~-x**-~n/~-x` which, adding parentheses to signify precedence, is
`(~-(x**(-~n)))/(~-x)` which is equivalent to
`(-1 - -1 * (x ** (-1 * (-1 - n))))/(-1 - -x)` which is equivalent to
`((x ** (n + 1)) - 1)/(x - 1)`

Comment: The same to JS answer: `+x**n` -> `*x+1` save 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
t⟦R&h;Rz^ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v@TR/GVBahnWQVVxD7dO0P7/P9pIR8HQMvZ/FAA)

Nothing particularly interesting, construct the range 0 to n, raise x to the power of each number in it.

And since I wanted to learn how `ᵃ`ccumulate works, here's a slightly longer version that uses that:

#### 15 bytes

```
,1↺⟨t×{bh}⟩ᵃ⁾k+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9icmFjaHlsb2cy//8sMeKGuuKfqHTDl3tiaH3in6nhtYPigb5rK///WzE5LCAyXf9a)

Form array [1, x], and do this n times, accumulating the results into that array after each iteration: multiply the last element of the array, by the second element of the array (i.e. x). Since this calculates [1, x, x^2, ... x^n, x^(n+1)], knife off the last value and add the rest of them up as the output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->x,n{(0..n).sum{|i|x**i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165CJ69aw0BPL09Tr7g0t7oms6ZCSyuztvZ/gUJatKGOUSwXiGGkYwxhGOuYwEQMLWP/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 42 bytes

```
lambda x,n:n+1if x<2else(x**(n+1)-1)/(x-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUaFCJ88qT9swM02hwsYoNac4VaNCS0sDKKKpa6ipr1EBJP//BwA)

Comment: Since x is guaranteed to be positive, I believe you can do `if x<2`.

Comment: @MarDev, ah yes that’s right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), 6 bytes

```
$0;A^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8XA2jFO5f9/IwVDSwA)

## Explanation

```
        Implicit inputs: A and n
$0      Zero indexing
  ;     Output sum of first n terms in sequence
   A^$  Each term is A to the power of the current index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,n:n<1or x*f(x,n-1)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoUInzyrPxjC/SKFCK00DyNM11NQ2/F9QlJlXopCmYahjpMkF4xjpGCM4xjomyDKGlpr/AQ)

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes**

```python
lambda x,n:1/x*-~n or~-x**-~n/~-x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ8/KUL9CS7cuTyG/qE63QgvE1Acy/hcUZeaVKKRpGOoYaXLBOEY6xgiOsY4JsoyhpeZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
#.1$~>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/5X1DFXq7Kz@a/43VEhTMOIyApLGXMZA0oTLqAJIGVoCAA)

#### How it works

```
#.1$~>:  Left argument = X, Right argument = N
  1$~>:  Generate a list of N+1 ones
#.       Interpret as base X digits and convert to single integer
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using  `>:` instead of `1+]`
[7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/5X1DFXq7Kz@a/43VEhTMOIyApLGXMZA0oTLqAJIGVoCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(x,n)sum(x.^(0:n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCJ0@zuDRXo0IvTsPAKk9T839iXrGGkY6hpeZ/AA)

Just learnt Octave 15 minutes ago for this challenge... Hoping it is already optimized.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

```apl
+/1,*∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBG19Qx2tRx0zHvVu/v/fUCFNwYjLCEgacxkDSRMw29ASAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
à╕F¬f£ù╞
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=85b846aa669c97c6&i=1+2%0A2+3%0A3+4%0A2+19&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>44</s>  34 bytes

Here's my naive and simple solution.

```python
f=lambda x,n:n>=0and x**n+f(x,n-1)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##FYpBDsIgEADP8Io9AtJEqBeb1Ft79Q1oISWpW7JipK9HvMwkk0lHXne0tYZxc6/H4qBoHPA2nh0uUJTCUxAtdUbW7xo3D2bgLNPRyBJFzBCEipg@WUjJmS9PnzJM93ki2gncG/x/9SW2oRptudU97/Wl2Vx/)

Comment: `r` is redundant, so `f=lambda x,n:n>=0and x**n+f(x,n-1)` is 34, although golfing that with `n>=0` -> ``~n `` we get my port of 33 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 38 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$x n=sum[x^i\\i<-[0..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLpUIhz7a4NDe6Ii4zJibTRjfaQE8vLzb2f3BJIlCVrYKKgpGCoeX/f8lpOYnpxf91PX3@u1TmJeZmJhcDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 32

```bash
echo $[`eval echo +$1**{0..$2}`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUJJaXJKcWJyqkJmnoGSoYKSkoGSkYAwkjRVMwGxDSyVrhZR8roKizLySNAUl1WIFWzsFJQUVmE6u4tQSBV1dhMD/1OSMfAWV6ITUssQcBTBHW8VQS6vaQE9Pxag2IfZ/Sn5e6n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) with GNU utilities, 23

```bash
seq -s+ -f$1^%g 0 $2|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYs7CgIxFAD7PcXwyFYSMFkbET2KsJ8X3SbRfSm9exRBbIZhYKbR7i2VjapW59GUNSOBKEhk@HDg8PVwlBNL6R7bmmtCeuN8QXC/szOteP8PzfSJtx0@uXDtb@xx8TXNbSlZ2xs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{sum $^a X**0..$^b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7q4NFdBJS5RIUJLy0BPTyUuqfZ/cWKlQpqGoY6RpjUXhG2kYwxnG@uYIIkbWmr@BwA)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                 }  # Anonymous code block
 sum    # Get the sum of
         X**   # The cross product with the meta operator exponential
     $^a            # With the first parameter
            0..$^b  # And the range of 0 to the second parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
l~),f#:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P6dOUydN2Ur7/39jBRMA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T@nTlMnTdlK@39BrYnWf0MFIy4jBWMuYwUTIG1oCQA).

#### Explanation

```
l      e# Read a line from STDIN
~      e# Evaluate: pushes x, then n
)      e# Add 1 to n
,      e# Range: gives [0 1 ... n]
f#     e# Map with extra parameter: gives [x^0 x^1 ... x^n]
:+     e# Fold addition over array: gives x^0 + x^1 + ... + x^n
       e# Implicit display in STDOUT
```

Comment: CJam... Now that's a name I haven't heard in a while

Comment: @BetaDecay Judge me by my age, do you?

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 21 bytes

```
(x,n)->sum(i=0,n,x^n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdJCoAwEAXRq3xcpaEDThsXehGJ0AhKIIbGAfT00YCreqWye7tqWtAnc3MkOxzXZnxfcuR7ipRENTxGYAfo7uP5schTYJYQzMIQIsY4VozafagZTW7DaP@vOucovQ)

Comment: You can take input via currying  to save 1 byte. [Demo](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7v0LXLk/Xrrg0VyPT1kAnT6ciLk/zf0FRZl6JRpqGsaaGiabmfwA).

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>78</s> <s>59</s> 40 bytes

```java
x->n->x>1?~-(int)Math.pow(x,n+1)/~-x:n+1
```

Uses the approach mentioned by *@flawr*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lY69DoIwFEZ3n@KObbQ1oIt/dTNxcHI0DhUBi/XSwEUxRl8da8RZ3U7ynXw5mT5rke2PTWR1WcJKG7x1AErSZCLI/CorMlYmFUZkcpSLFqZLpDiNi95vUgtKQQKzphYKhapVMH8IZpD4StNBuvzC6h52A95/iHrsoZn4FlftrG9pk8652cPJZ7I1FQbTzRY0fyUDrK8lxSeZVySdn8giS6R2zl5ZwFsIOZ98k8OPPPhBHnzk4T/Pweht3zv35gk)

**Explanation:**

```java
x->n->                     // Method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  x>1?                     //  If `x` is larger than 1:
   ~-(int)Math.pow(x,n+1)  //   Return `x` to the power of `n+1` - 1
   /~-x                    //   integer-divided by `x-1`
  :                        //  Else:
   n+1                     //   Return `n+1` as result instead
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
⊣⊥1⍴⍨1+⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEddix91LTV81LvlUe8KQ@1HXYv@/zdUSFMw4jICksZcxkDSBMw2tAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 49 bytes

Throws errors, but still works I guess.

```
f(_,0,1).
f(X,N,Y):-M is N-1,f(X,M,Z),Y is Z+X^N.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P00jXsdAx1BTjytNI0LHTydS00rXVyGzWMFP11AHJOSrE6WpEwkSidKOiPPTA2kx0jG0BKrUAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

Your usual, everyday recursive solution.

```c
f(b,e,t,i){for(t=1,i=e;i--;t*=b);t=e--?t+f(b,e):1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYrBDoIwEAXvfEWDMeliawJ6shY/xHCA0sImCKauXAjfXosX423ezDOyMybscDTDu7Xs@qIWp2NfJn9qwCa64HgjrCCBsLjJc9K5QG0VSqko0w0o0lbKGx2@R7jkag04EnvUOPINat8ZYfrasyyLPANbEsbQ8S2UBbCnjzfH032bimhpwi3N97wC8VtFBQAqWUM4hfMH)

Comment: `f(x,n,v){for(v=1;n--;v=v*x+1);x=v;}`

Comment: `f(b,e){b=e?pow(b,e--)+f(b,e):1;}`

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
Ｉ↨ＮＥ⊕Ｎ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUDDMy@5KDU3Na8kNUUjQ1NHISC/PLUIoqQQyM3UBAHr//@NFUz@65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses @Bubbler's algorithm. Explanation:

```
     Ｎ  Second input as a number
    ⊕   Increment
   Ｅ  ¹ Make list of `1`s of that length
  Ｎ     First input as a number
 ↨      Base conversion
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
AQVhH=+Z^GN)Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zEwLMPDVjsqzt1PM@r/fyMdQ0sA)

**How it works**

```
assign('Q',eval_input())
assign('[G,H]',Q)
for N in num_to_range(head(H)):
 assign('Z',plus(Z,Ppow(G,N)))
imp_print(Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 61 bytes

```
@set s=0
@for /l %%i in (0,1,%2)do @set/as=s*%1+1
@echo %s%
```

Using @tsh's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4.0](https://sourceforge.net/p/swift), 100 bytes

```
func a(x:Int,n:Int)->Int{return(0...n).reduce(0,{p,q in p+(q>=1 ?(1...q).reduce(1,{a,_ in a*x}):1)})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc6xCoMwFIXh3ae4OCVtjCZxMVA7dOresVCCjeASNIlUEJ89TZaK0OVMH4fffYbe1yH0s@lAoUXejScmLS7auKvVfrYGVZRSg6nV77nTqCLrSCYYDIxnNLUXBlfEoph@gpFVkVcS6rRsWDK84S3LyhIe2nm4KaddNtrBeJQvkhEwkkPRwhOlCBYTOMY53glPROyERyKORCRS70REUv95Yc3xhjUJhfAF)

#### Ungolfed

```
func a(x:Int, n:Int) -> Int {
  return (0...n).reduce(0,        // For 0 to n
    { p, q in                     // p is result of last cycle, q the current element
      p +                         // Add p to
      ( q > 0 ?                   // If current element is not 0 
        (1...q).reduce(1, { a, _ in a*x } ) // pow(x, n) *
        : 1                       // Otherwise, 1
      ) 
    } 
  )
}

* The reduce is shorter than:
import Foundation
[...] Int(pow(Double(x),Double(q)))
```

First golf I do, so could be much more golfable, but finally the super-verbose Swift has a chance to be used!